# Graphiti can not call method with args including keyword inside attribute/extra_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphiti

my environment:
Ruby 3.1.3
Rails 7.0.4
Graphiti 1.3.9
Graphiti-rails 0.4.0

I faced this issue

```
extra_attribute :attribute_name, :array do
  get_my_age(@object, date: Date.current)
end

def get_my_age(birth, date:)
end
```

it will throw `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: date)):`

but, if I try with

```
extra_attribute :attribute_name, :array do
  wrapper(@object, Date.current)
end

def wrapper(a, b)
  get_my_age(a, date: b)
end

def get_my_age(birth, date:)
end
```

it will not throw any errors.

Which am I wrong? or is this a bug of graphiti?